# Is it possible to work hide a folder from a full slug of a page with Nextjs SSG and Storyblok

Tags: next.js, static-site-generation, storyblok

Due to the structure of my Storyblok Space, I'm unable to rewrite the final slugs to match my desired URL structure.

Inside Storyblok, I have to use the [folder level translation](https://www.storyblok.com/tp/setup-field-and-folder-level-translation) and due to business rules, inside the language folders, I have to group stories inside "virtual folders".
The structure inside my root folder and the desired final paths are:

- `en/website/home` - `en/home`
- `en/website/about` - `en/about`
- `en/website/category/business` - `en/category/business`
- `en/landing-page/example-lp` - `en/example-lp`
- `es/website/home` - `es/home`
- `es/website/sobre` - `es/sobre`

> In this cases, `website` and `langing-page` are "virtual folders".

Using NextJS SSG, I am able to use [`getStaticPaths`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-paths) and [`getStaticProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props) with the Storyblok API and generate the pages with the full slug. This is achieved with a `[[...slug]].js` file inside my `pages` folder.

If I work with only one virtual path, for example `website/`, I can just return the `getStaticPaths` params as follows:

```js
[{
    params: { slug: ['about'] }, // without the 'website' value
    locale: 'en',
}]
```

Just appending the virtual folder on the API request, inside `getStaticProps`, generates the files according to the desired path.

```js
let { data } = await Storyblok.get(`cdn/stories/${params.locale}/website/${params.slug}`, option)
```

The drawback of this approach is that I must use only one virtual folder. I could not create structure where I could send dynamically the virtual folder parameter separately so it could be appended on the Storyblok request URL.

What I tried so far:

- I was able to use the `rewrites` key inside my `next.config.js` to dynamically hide the vitrual folders. However, it does not affect my server side generated files.
- Use [**Storyblok Advanced paths**](https://www.storyblok.com/apps/advanced-paths) app to return the `real_path` of the stories on the `cdn/links/` request. And even though I can setup the correct values to the `real_path` parameter, without the virtual folder reference I cannot request the stories correctly inside `getStaticProps`.
- I wasn't able to modify the slug values of the responses from the Storyblok API.
- I wasn't able to return an additional parameter to the `getStaticPaths` method. For example:

```js
[{
    params: { slug: ['about'], folder: ['website'] },
    locale: 'en',
}]
```

Or even:

```js
[{
    params: { slug: ['about'] },
    locale: 'en',
    folder: 'website'
}]
```

**Obs:** The object above kinda works if I change my project's folder structure to `pages/[folder]/[...slug].js`. However, even though I can access the `folder` parameter inside `getStaticProps`, it also goes to the final paths

Any suggestion, or different approaches to solve it is very welcome.